# Как работать с множеством маленьких объектов в gui?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, gui, объекты

Допустим, снежинки, все они должны двигаться асинхронно, но их слишком много и запускать для каждого свой поток не кажется разумным. У каждой снежинки в методе "падения" должны выполняться свои преобразования и выходить разные данные. Может я что-то не так понимаю или всё так и должно быть с уймой потоков?

Comment: Если проблем с рендерингом такой уймы снежинок нет, то что мешает заниматься трансформированием этих объектов в одном потоке? Как и ваш коллега с матричным дождём, вы выбрали не лучшее средства для решения своей проблемы. Рекомендую посмотреть в сторону DirectX/OpenGL/Vulcan, в том числе в виде вьюпортов в WPF. Они прекрасно справятся с поставленной задачей. В любом случае, без примера существующего кода сложно что-либо советовать. Покажите или расскажите более детализированно о текущем решении.

Comment: Тут не нужны потоки, делайте обычный List<Snowflake>, в своём контейнере Snowflake храните все данные касательно параметров снежинки, и текущих флагов перемещения. Останется написать сервис, который будет в цикле перебирать снежинки, менять их внутреннее состояние, рассчитывать новые положения, повороты и т.д., + отрисовывать их на полотне.